# Is it usual to complete an extensive medical form for an office-based role?

Tags: new-job, united-kingdom

I have just got all the paperwork through for starting a new job, and part of it is a very extensive medical form that basically wants to know my entire medical history,  whether it affects my work or not.

I have quizzed it, as some of my history is personal, has no effect on my ability to do a job, and is unlikely ever to cause a problem at work, and have essentially been told that they need it for 'Health and Safety' reasons, and there could be problems if I left anything out. It was also implied that they thought I was being awkward - which of course isn't the impression I want to give!

This is the first time in my career (several companies) that anyone has requested such an extensive medical history for work - is this usual in the UK?

Comment: sounds like company policy, some HR person thought it would be a great idea, rather than it being normal, but I'm not familiar with the UK, will be interesting to read the answers

Comment: Where I am from, asking detailed questions about ones medical history might actually be illegal, especially when you are not working in a field where hygiene is important. But I have no idea how UK laws see this.

Comment: It may have something to do with the equality act as outlined [here](http://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/2313.aspx?CategoryID=190&SubCategoryID=1905), but im not sure.

Comment: In germany, other then problems directly related to future work performance, any medical history is none of the employers business.

Comment: Does th job include private health insurance?

Answer (score 3):

Normal in that it happens with most companies? Nope, the vast majority won't bother at all, or will simply ask whether you have any disability that could affect your work

Normal in that it happens sometimes? Sure. I had one when applying for my current job within the NHS (no fly-by-night cowboy firm, for sure... And they tend to know a thing or two about health).

I wouldn't see it as anything problematic or unusual. They probably don't actually **need** the entire form for an office job, but for them it's easier to just make sure it's complete for everyone and that way they don't risk making a mistake. If they offer health or travel/life insurance benefits or similar, it may even be related to that and be part and parcel of you receiving those benefits

Comment: I've had the same at a major UK bank, it can be as much about making an accommodation for someone who needs it as anything else.

Comment: I agree, I've also seen HR pull these sorts of things out of nowhere just because someone who didn't have enough to do made a form.

Comment: +1 I've had this once in the UK, and it was because the company's long-term-sickness insurer required it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have just got all the paperwork through for starting a new job, and
>   part of it is a very extensive medical form that basically wants to
>   know my entire medical history,

Its definately not normal for office based roles, and depending on the exact laws in your country it may even be flat out illegal (I know it is in my country, not sure about the UK, but IANAL).

So my advice would be to consult with an actual lawyer wether or not the company is even allowed to ask for this.

But its definately not normal.